# Real integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} $ with the help of complex friends

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration

I have to solve the integral $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} $$ by doing this:

Given a rectangle that is defined by the points $ r+i, -r+i,-r-i,r-i$, $r>0$ and $\gamma_r$ is a closed positively oriented curve around the boundary of this rectangle. Then I should proof that $$ \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\gamma_r} \frac{1}{z} dz=2\pi i.$$

And by using this, I am supposed to evaluate $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}. $$

There are two things that look difficult to me, the first one is: Why is there a limit for the first integral?  Cause by using Cauchy's integral theorem this should be the same as the integral around the circle $$C: \gamma(t)=|r+i|e^{it}$$ and therefore 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{|r+i|e^{it}}^{i|r+i|e^{it}} dt=2 \pi i.$$

So there is no limit necessary, which makes me thinking that this way should be wrong.

The second thing I do not understand is, how both integrals are related to each other?

Comment: what would be the advantage of a half-circle?

Comment: no problem, thanks for your ideas

Comment: I guess this is a complex analysis exercise. But I can't resist pointing out that the integrand here has an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: I think when you will parameterize integrals of $1/z$ over the four sides of the rectangle, the first integral will magically appear.

Comment: I will give it try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write down the integrals over the four sides of the rectangle:
\begin{align}
&I_1=\int_{r-i}^{r+i}\frac{dz}{z}=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{idt}{r+it},\\
&I_2=\int_{r+i}^{-r+i}\frac{dz}{z}=-\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{dt}{t+i},\\
&I_3=\int_{-r+i}^{-r-i}\frac{dz}{z}=-\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{idt}{-r+it},\\
&I_4=\int_{-r-i}^{r-i}\frac{dz}{z}=\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{dt}{t-i}.
\end{align}
Next consider the sum
$$I_2+I_4=\int_{-r}^{r}\left(\frac{1}{t-i}-\frac{1}{t+i}\right)dt=2i\int_{-r}^r\frac{dt}{1+t^2}.$$
The limit of this sum as $r\rightarrow\infty$ is proportional to the integral we want to find. On the other hand, the limit of $I_1$ and $I_3$ is zero (they are both $O(1/r)$).

Hence we can write
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}(I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4)=2i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^2+1}=2\pi i,$$
which gives the answer.